# Passing filter as object from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filtering, paging

I'm trying to implement filtering and paging in a MVC controller. I pass information to View using ViewBag.

Filter class is this:

```
public class Criteria
{
    public int? SnapshotKey { get; set; }
    public string Delq { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string[] Ares = new string[2];
        if (SnapshotKey.HasValue)
            Ares[0] = "SnapshotKey=" + SnapshotKey.ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Delq))
            Ares[1] = "Delq=" + Delq;

        return String.Join("&", Ares.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
    }
}
```

My controller method is like this:

```
public ActionResult Search(Criteria filter, string filterString, 
                           int pageNo = 1, int pageSize = 5)
{
    using (DemoDBEntities db = new DemoDBEntities())
    {
        var list = db.BMH.AsQueryable();
        if (filter != null)
        {
            if (filter.SnapshotKey.HasValue)
                list = list.Where(r => r.SnapshotKey == filter.SnapshotKey.Value);
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Delq))
                list = list.Where(r => r.Delq == filter.Delq);
        }
        list = list.OrderBy(r=>r.SnapshotKey).Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        ViewBag.Criteria = filter.ToString();
        ViewBag.CriteriaString = filterString;
        ViewBag.PageNo = pageNo;
        return View(list.ToList());
    }
}
```

AFAIK, I cannot pass ViewBag as an object to controller, that's why I used filter.ToString() to store the current filter.

In View, I have below link to go to specific page, while preserving current filter.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next Page", "Search", new { filter = ViewBag, filterString = ViewBag.CriteriaString, pageNo = ViewBag.PageNo + 1, pageSize = 5 })
```

So when coming back from View, I get current filter as string. Now in controller I need to convert string to Criteria class. It is doable but I'm looking for a more decent way to do what I need.

Comment: Why not just `new { SnapshotKey = ViewBag.SnapshotKey, Delq = ViewBag.Delq, pageNo = ViewBag.PageNo + 1.... }` (and you can simplify it even further by adding `pageNo` and `pageSize` to you model so the POST method is just `public ActionResult Search(Criteria filter)`

Comment: I'm trying to not depend on every filed name and want to not change it if I added a new field to the Criteria class. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well if you add a new field, then you need to update the `.ToString()` method (i.e. something has to be updated). You could always add the `pageNo` and `pageSize` to you `Criteria` model and include them in the `ToString()` method, and then just generate the link using `<a href="@Url.Action("Search")?@ViewBag.Criteria>Next Page</a>`

Comment: Not very elegant though, and you could use reflection to loop each property in the model to build the query string so you not hard coding every property/value.

Comment: Right, This resolves the controller part, but when user clicks on [Next] and program goes back to controller, I need to know what is the current filter (in Search action) so I can rebuild the list of rows using LINQ. Also not using a class for filter makes me change the signature of the Search action every time I add a new field to filter.

Comment: But that will pass the values - it will generate `href="..../Search?SnapshotKey=xx&Delq=yy&pageNo=1&pageSize=5"` (assuming you provide all values) which will then bind to the properties of your `Critera` model. You method just needs to be `public ActionResult Search(Criteria filter)`

Comment: I don't get this part: " bind to the properties of your Critera model". assume all parameters are in a single class (Criteria), how I can write the @Html.ActionLink in View w/o naming every single field. If you know the solution, would you please write is as answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129292/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-flicker).

Comment: Oops. I'm at works and my network policy doesn't allow me to use SO chat :(

Comment: You cannot use `@Html.ActionLink()` - but you can generate the link manually as I noted in a previous comment - `<a href="@Url.Action("Search")?@ViewBag.Criteria>Next Page</a>` where `ViewBag.Criteria = filter.ToString();` (except that you would need to increment the value of page first)

Comment: Oh, I see. So instead of using ActionLink, I should use html link. Let me try. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `filterString` in the `Search()` method will be a string in the format `name=value&name=value...` so you could first using `String.Split()` (on the `&` character) to create an array of `name=value` items, and then split again (on the `=` character) to get the property names and values, but that is all getting messy and it would be easier to just build the whole query string and have it bind directly to your `Criteria` model.

Change the model to include all properties, including `pageNo` and pageSize`

```
public class Criteria
{
    public Criteria() // perhaps add some defaults?
    {
        PageNo = 1;
        PageSize = 5;
    }
    public int? SnapshotKey { get; set; }
    public string Delq { get; set; }
    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    .... // see method below
}
```

Then to make it flexible and allow you to add more 'criteria' properties, use reflection to build the query string

```
    public string ToQueryString(int pageIncrement)
    {
        List<string> propValues = new List<string>();
        foreach(var prop in GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var name = prop.Name;
            var value = prop.GetValue(this);
            if (name == "PageNo")
            {
                value == (int)value + pageIncrement;
            }
            if (value != null)
            {
                propValues .Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", name, value));
            }
        }
        return "?" + String.Join("&", propValues);
    }
```

The code in the controller will then be

```
public ActionResult Search(Criteria filter)
{
    using (DemoDBEntities db = new DemoDBEntities())
    {
        var list = db.BMH.AsQueryable();
        if (filter != null)
        {
            if (filter.SnapshotKey.HasValue)
                list = list.Where(r => r.SnapshotKey == filter.SnapshotKey.Value);
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Delq))
                list = list.Where(r => r.Delq == filter.Delq);
        }
        list = list.OrderBy(r => r.SnapshotKey).Skip((filter.PageNo - 1) * pageSize).Take(filter.PageSize);
        ViewBag.Criteria = filter;
        return View(list.ToList());
    }
}
```

and then in the view

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Search")@ViewBag.Criteria.ToQueryString(-1)">Previous</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Search")@ViewBag.Criteria.ToQueryString(1)">Next</a>
```

Note also that you could just use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Search", (yourAssembly.Criteria)ViewBag.Criteria)
```

assuming that `Criteria` contains only simple properties, meaning the `ToQueryString()` method is not required. However you would need to increment/decrement the value of the `PageNo` property before using `ActionLink()`, for example

```
@{ var criteria = (yourAssembly.Criteria)ViewBag.Criteria; }
@{ criteria.PageNo = @criteria.PageNo - 1; }
@Html.ActionLink("Previous", "Search", criteria)
@{ criteria.PageNo = @criteria.PageNo + 2; }
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Search", criteria)
```

Comment: Well Done. Thank you!